# Windows executable running 100 times slower when has a particular filename

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Fixed: I ran an application called Application Verifier while debugging my allinone project a while ago. Application Verifier kept running in the background and was keeping a log every time I ran allinone.exe. I suspect the growing number of log files was the cause allinone.exe started to slow down. I was able to find that out using the Process Monitor, which I didn't know about earlier. Thank you!

Comment: I would bet a (false) Compatibility DB match or inspection to see if its an installer of some kind.  You could see if procmon provide any clues.

Comment: Also try temporarily disabling your AV and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Can you use some disassembler or ProcMon to see what happens internally?

Comment: Temporarily disabling Anti-Virus didn't help. Still looking into Process Monitoring, but no breakthrough yet

Comment: This is Stack Overflow. Instead of editing your question to include the answer, you should post it separately and accept it.

Comment: Fixed: I ran an application called Application Verifier while debugging my allinone project a while ago. Application Verifier kept running in the background and was keeping a log every time I ran allinone.exe. I suspect the growing number of log files was the cause allinone.exe started to slow down. I was able to find that out using the Process Monitor, which I didn't know about earlier. Thank you everyone!

Comment: It's not the log files.  Application Verifier can impact the performance of your app.  By renaming your executable, Application Verifier will no longer hook into it when it runs.  A simpler fix would be to run the Application Verifier UI and remove your image name from the list of applications that will trigger it.